# SQL query to select records between two dates using only year and month

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a initial and final date, for example: `01/06/2018` and `01/03/2019` and I want to get the records stored in the SQL Server database but only using year and month.

I've tried this code but it does not return me any record. I also tried the code but only with the YEAR limitation (removed the month) and returns all records between those two years.

```vb
If tem_permissao Then

  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rsImportar = New ADODB.Recordset

  'gets the year and month from inital and final year and month                              
  date1 = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
  init_year = Year(date1)
  init_month = Month(date1)
  date2 = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
  fin_year = Year(date2)
  fin_month = Month(date2)

  conn.Open sConnString
  Set rsImportar = conn.Execute("SELECT INSTALATION, VALUE, USER, DATA, HISTORIC FROM dbo.VALUES WHERE ID_VARIAVEL = " & sID_VARIAVEL & " AND YEAR >= " & init_year & " AND YEAR <= " & fin_year & " AND MONTH >= " & init_month & " AND MONTH <= " & fin_month & ";") 

  ' Transfer result

  Sheets(2).Range("D2").CopyFromRecordset rsImportar

  rsImportar.Close

  TRANSFERED = TRANSFERED + 1
  .Cells(iRowNo, 9).Value = "Record Transfered"

End If
```

Comment: Show data and expected result .....

Comment: Either change YEAR and MONTH into an actual date or concatenate in YYYYMM format and compare that way.  You cannot do this with the separate statements above.

Comment: @Gareth        What if i convert the YEAR and MONTH to a datevalue before doing this. That probably would work right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the other way of doing it.  The important thing is that the fields are combined before doing the query.  Also check out `BETWEEN` as it simplifies things.